# Creating a tuple of image pairs

Tags: python, loops, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to loop through my subdirectories where each of them contains two images. I'm trying to read those two images, and put them as a pair in a tuple. This is what I did:

```
import os
import os.path
from PIL import Image
import cv2

path = '/Users/abc/Desktop/images'
pairs = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith('1'):
            im1 = cv2.imread(root + '/' + '1.jpg')
        elif file.startswith('2'):
            im2 = cv2.imread(root + '/' + '2.jpg')

    pair = (im1,im2)
    pairs.append(pair)
```

I however get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_pair.py", line 16, in <module>
    pair = (im1,im2)
NameError: name 'im1' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: please post your imagename list, so we can decide how to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original answer:

Declare and assign the variables before the loop. I don't think it is really a good method, but your question contains so little useful information to make a good solution.

```
import os
import os.path
from PIL import Image
import cv2

path = '/Users/abc/Desktop/images'
pairs = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):

    im1 = None
    im2 = None

    for file in files:
        if file.startswith('1'):
            im1 = cv2.imread(root + '/' + '1.jpg')
        elif file.startswith('2'):
            im2 = cv2.imread(root + '/' + '2.jpg')

    ## TODO: make sure im1 and im2 is `OK`
    # ..

    pair = (im1,im2)
    pairs.append(pair)
```

---

Update:

**1.** Take this code snape for example:

```
def test(x):
    # just for testing
    for i in range(x):
        if i%2 :
            i1 = i # last odd
        else:
            i2 = i # last even
    print(i1, i2)
```

1) The `if-condition` doesn't satisfy, then the code does not be executed, the variable havn't be assigned when referenced.

```
>>> test(1)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i1' referenced before assignment
```

2) Local assigned variables in `for-loop` may still exist(if not be deleted by GC) when go outside of the `loop`.

```
>>> test(5)
3 4
```

**2.** Then if we want to use the variables no matter the  conditions satisfy, we can declare and assign the variables first. But make sure to `check whether the variable is OK`.

```
def test2(x):
    # just for testing
    i1,i2 = None, None # declare and assign the variables 
    for i in range(x):
        if i%2 :
            i1 = i # last odd
        else:
            i2 = i # last even

    print(i1, i2)
```

Declare and assign the variables before used, no  syntax error occurs.

But `remember to check whether value is ok` (I don't think `None` is ok though).

```
>>> test2(1)
None 0       
>>> test2(5)
3 4
```

Comment: Going to guess additionally that the pair should be appended inside the `for` loop, but otherwise good catch with the local variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `im1` not declaring. I mean this line,

```
im1 = cv2.imread(root + '/' + '1.jpg')
```

Make sure that you have going through all conditions. Else declare a default value for `im1` and `im2` before for loop.

Answer (score 1):

'IF' condition for im1 is not satisfied. It might be due to two reasons 1. File (1.jpg) doesnot exists. 2. File name will be different like ' 1.jpg' or '~1.jpg' etc. check it care fully. Add statement 'print files' to check the files in the location

```
import os
import os.path
from PIL import Image
import cv2

path = '/Users/abc/Desktop/images'
pairs = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith('1'): 
            im1 = cv2.imread(root + '/' + '1.jpg')
        elif file.startswith('2'):
            im2 = cv2.imread(root + '/' + '2.jpg')

    pair = (im1,im2)
    pairs.append(pair)
```